# Unable to view mongodb locally hosted on our server in compass

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have hosted a MERN stack application on our internal server and its working good however I'm trying to view the database in Mongodb compass however its saying ""Econn refused"" . Can someone help me on how to overcome this?

Comment: is your local MongoDB running?

Comment: Yes its running and MY application is able to access it, I m trying to find the config file of mongodb on our server to change the bind_ip but no luck though

Comment: Are you using the same connection string in Compass as you use for your app?

Comment: yes Indeed the same string

Comment: have you used correct credentials? and the password you provide need to be encoded

Comment: Are you trying to use Compass on the same host as your app?

Comment: Yes I'm using compass on same network as my app

Comment: "same network" is different than "same host".  Could there be a firewall issue?

Comment: I have even added my machine's Ip address to mongodb config BindIp option, yes there is a firewall but not sure if its the reason